# php how to use variable inside another class

Tags: php

Iam learning php these days. I have one query below:

```
class A {

var $a;

}

class B extends A{

var $b = $a; //here its showing me error, i even tried as '$this->$a' but still showing error. so, how do I use $a in class B? ( instead of using in a function ), 

}
```

I am declaring $b just inside class instead of inside a function because I need to use $b variable in many places inside my php file.

So, please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28988260/3933332

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
<?php

class firstname 
{
   public static $name='Your First Name';
}
class lastname
{
   public static $last='Your Last Name';
}
class Fullname
{

     public static function staticValue() {
        return firstname::$name."--".lastname::$last;
    }
}

print Fullname::staticValue() . "\n";
?>
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

1.) use `public` instead of `var`
2.) when you extending `a` class, you have got access to properties of this parent. So you don't need to declare $b, you can just use `$this->a`

```
class a {
    $a = 'test';
}

class b extends a {
   public function get() {
       echo $this->a;
   }
}

$b = new b;
$b->get(); // prints test
```