# how to load dynamic vars in class in php

Tags: php, class, static

I have a problem to load dinamic configs in static class.

I have something like this:

```
class ololo {
public static $config = array(
    'time' => time(),
    'name' => 'zztop_'.mt_rand(1,1000)
    );
public static function getVar($name) {
    return self::$config[$name];
}
}
```

How should i do to make it work?
I have many dynamic vars and i cant load it in __construct.

I want everytime i call a getVar have new value to show.
Something like:

```
echo ololo::getVar('name');
echo ololo::getVar('name');
echo ololo::getVar('name');

zztop_1
zztop_222
zztop_11
```

Comment: You can't the value in the class definition has to be a constant value. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: any idea how i can save dynamic values?

I have several configs to load and some of them have dynamic values...
I have no idea how to save configs to onload where i need it. and reload to get new values...

Comment: It is not possible. Variable values can only be set at run-time.

Comment: @Kolgarn See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28988260/3933332