# php OOP example - can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

    class titleGenerator {
        public $names = array(
        'Best Beer',
        'Happy Burgers',
        'Alexs Nachos',
        'Big Sams Tacos'
        );
        public $i = rand(0, count($names)-1);

        public function sayTitle() {
            echo $names[$i];
        }
    }

    $titles = new titleGenerator;
    $titles->sayTitle();
?>
```

I'm trying to learn OOP and made this kind of example but it doesn't work and can someone help?

Comment: How does it not work? What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: You need to use the constructor.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28988260/3933332

Comment: you can't initialize $i in declaration of class. You need to do this in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
public $i = rand(0, count($names)-1);
```

Is wrong. You can't define a class property like that in php. You will have to set it in the constructor, also, from the `sayTitle` method, you should be using `$this->names` instead of `$names`:

```
<?php

    class titleGenerator {
        public $names = array(
        'Best Beer',
        'Happy Burgers',
        'Alexs Nachos',
        'Big Sams Tacos'
        );
        public $i;

        public function __construct() {
             $this->i = rand(0, count($this->names)-1)
        }

        public function sayTitle() {
            echo $this->names[$this->i];
        }
    }

    $titles = new titleGenerator();
    $titles->sayTitle();
?>
```

Note that now you will have to instantiate the object with parenthesis in order to call the constructor method:

```
$titles = new titleGenerator();
```

Comment: Yes, I made the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it helped me but to make code run right I made this:
`

```
class titleGenerator {
    public $names = array(
    'Best Beer',
    'Happy Burgers',
    'Alexs Nachos',
    'Big Sams Tacos'
    );

    public $i;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->i = rand(0, count($this->names)-1);
    }

    public function sayTitle() {
        echo $this->names[$this->i];
    }
}

$titles = new titleGenerator;
$titles->sayTitle();
```

?>`