# In PHP, how can I use a variable as the value in a key=>value pair when defining a public variable for a class?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to use environment variables to set our database secrets. They are defined in a class. Copied here. I am getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "Unexpected '$_SERVER'"

Not allowing use of variables.

Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
        public $default = array(
                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_HOST'],
                'login' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_LOGIN'],
                'password' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_PASSWORD'],
                'database' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE'],
                'prefix' => ''
                //'encoding' => 'utf8',
            );
  }
```

Comment: Assign it in the `__construct()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988260/is-it-possible-to-define-a-class-property-value-dynamically-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the `__construct` method and populate variable like this:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
  public $default = [];
  public function __construct(){
      $this->default = array(
              'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
              'persistent' => false,
              'host' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_HOST'],
              'login' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_LOGIN'],
              'password' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_PASSWORD'],
              'database' => $_SERVER['DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE'],
              'prefix' => ''
              //'encoding' => 'utf8',
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's invalid syntax. As pointed out in the comments, assign that within `__construct()`. The best approach would be to pass the variables through as a parameter.

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

        public $default;

        public function __construct($default)
        {
            $this->default = array(
                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => $default['DB_DEFAULT_HOST'],
                'login' => $default['DB_DEFAULT_LOGIN'],
                'password' => $default['DB_DEFAULT_PASSWORD'],
                'database' => $default['DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE'],
                'prefix' => ''
                //'encoding' => 'utf8',
            );
        }

  }

  // Usage
  $foo = new DATABASE_CONFIG($_SERVER);
```